# Unable to find "Speaker Recognition"

Tags: azure

"Speaker Recognition" is not found  under "Create a Resource"-> Marketplace.

In a similar scenario, while creating Text Analytics and I could find the term "Text Analytics" while typing and by entering search.

Any idea why this is not working for Speaker Recognition?

Answer (score 0):

The service in Azure is just called "speech"

[image]